# Best way to very quickly match a needle against a large haystack

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

Think of an employee management system application, now add a biometric machine to it. Users can swipe their finger to clock in and out of the system as they enter and exit the building.

So far my application currently can successfully enroll fingerprint templates retrieved from my biometric machine and have it saved into the database in a `blob`/`varchar` field.

I have over 3000 registered users in this local database of mine on a local mac app that I created. Now I am implementing the matching algorithm, and wondering whether I should:

1. load all 3000 fingerprint templates from the local database - the haystack - into an `NSMutableArray` with one database call that would be done at application startup and then match the user's fingerprint template - needle - against the haystack for each user that enters or exits the building;
2. Make multiple SQL calls returning one element of the haystack at a time, compare it with the needle, and if they dont match, return another element from the haystack until they match. Or,
3. Grab portions of the haystack (say a 100 fingerprint templates at a time) and load that into an `NSMutableArray` and then match the needle against that haystack subset.

Which is best for a lightning fast approach?

The fingerprint SDK I am using atm, is meant to be lightning fast in terms of the fingerprint verification itself, but I need to handle the database side of things and managing the haystack and needle myself and would ideally like that to be fast too.

**I am currently using SQLite, if I need adopt Cocoa Core Data to fulfil a better approach to what I wish to accomplish, then I am all ears and can adopt the system to provide a better user experience in terms of speed**

Here's an example of what one fingerprint template data looks like in a base 64 encoded string format.

[image]

Comment: Retrieving the elements one at a time is likely to be the slowest, but beyond that you'd have to profile it to be sure. I'd look at calculating a hash on the fingerprint data and searching for that, but that might not be possible for your system.

Answer (score 2):

3000 records seems like a tiny haystack. How big is a template? I'd almost certainly just load it all up into memory if you need to do complicated comparisons provided the templates aren't outrageously large.

The various approaches don't sound difficult to implement. Which way are you doing it now, and what's the performance bottleneck? Start by implementing simply, and then see if there's a problem. Often there isn't, and you spend a lot of time making things complicated for nothing.

Comment: +1 for explaining that sometimes one can just complicate the matter when there really isnt anything to worry about.

Comment: Hey Rob, please see the updated post. I've attached an image of what a fingerprint template looks like in a base 64 encoded string. That current template has 3831 characters.

Comment: I've been thinking of loading all the fingerprint templates in one go into an array and have each fingerprint thats swiped by users through out the day to be matched up against the array in memory. Does that sound like the way to go? And for any new users registered, to add that fingerprint template to the database of course and then reload the array with the updated database ready for matching again

Comment: Whatever is convenient. 7.5MB of memory (2500*3000) is really not that much to store your most important data. I'd stay focused on ease of correct implementation than saving a few MB of memory. Once you have a solid, working implementation, you can then profile it against more memory-efficient solutions. (I would store and work with the data as NSData, not as Base-64 encodings, though.) If you had millions of records, obviously you would need to be considering this problem from the beginning, but your data set just is so small I wouldn't spend much time worrying about it.

Comment: Wow, ok I never actually calculated it. Thats definitely of great help, thank you Rob. As for working with nsdata instead, I can do that, as it would mean I dont have to decode the Base-64 encoding strings, and can skip that step entirely x3000. And what do I do, just save the NSData object in the SQLite database straight away and then when returning that object, just cast it to an NSData object? I didnt it was possible to save an NSData object into a database.

Comment: This brings me onto the first question I asked in my post (two fold question), whether to use Core Data or SQLite. Could you also answer the first question too whether this simple database scheme should be setup with Core Data or SQLite? The scema will essentially have the following field names: employeeId, employeeName, and EmployeeFingerPrintTemplate

Comment: SQLite can store data as the Blob type. As for choosing, the question is whether you need a database or object persistence. If you're persisting a graph of objects, that's Core Data. If you're storing and searching for records, that's generally a database. Core Data is not a database. You think about the problems differently. Again, with 3000 records, it isn't a performance question. It's a question of how you think about your data; do you have records or objects? http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html

Answer (score 2):

3800 base 64 chars is only 2500 bytes...
just test it, try strnstr (null chars will stop it from searching), I bet you can search that hundreds of times a second.
be sure to search decoded otherwise because of alignment your needle could look like lots of different things.

Comment: I'll give it a go now. Could you also answer the first question too whether this simple database scheme should be setup with Core Data or SQLite? The scema will essentially have the following field names: `employeeId`, `employeeName`, and `EmployeeFingerPrintTemplate` etc.

Comment: you should try to do the easiest thing first, write some unit tests, and see if you have a need for more optimization... having said that, if you need to store the records as strings... storing in hex would allow textual search, where base 64 gets cyclically munged.